# MDT 2012 - KeyboardLocale, SkipTimeZone don't work

Tags: timezone, mdt-2012

I am trying out image deployment using MDT. IT is a wonderful tool to do lite-touch deployment, however the automation does not do exactly what I expected.

eg. I have the following in the CustomSettings.ini:

```
[Locale]
SkipLocaleSelection=YES
InputLocale=en-GB
SystemLocale=en-GB
UserLocale=en-GB
KeyboardLocale=en-GB
UILanguage=eb-US
```

I also have this in the bootstrap.ini:

```
KeyboardLocale=en-GB
```

However I still get the welcome page asking me to select keyboard locale (defaults to USA). I even tried to put the whole bunch in the bootstrap.ini:

```
SkipLocaleSelection=YES
InputLocale=en-GB
SystemLocale=en-GB
UserLocale=en-GB
KeyboardLocale=en-GB
UILanguage=eb-US
```

Apart from this, although I have this in the customsetting.ini, I still get asked to select time zone (the page with the calendar on it):

```
[Time zone]
SkipTimeZone=YES
TimeZoneName=Universal Time Coordinated
```

I googled and checked the reference, cannot find what's wrong with my settings. Anyone with more experience? Anything is welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value for `TimeZone` of "Universal Time Coordinated" is not valid.  It should simply be "UTC".

You want the Time Zone ID, not the Display Name.

You can use `tzutil /l` from a command line to list all valid display names, with their corresponding Id values.

```
C:\>tzutil /?
Windows Time Zone Utility

...

    /l Lists all valid time zone IDs and display names. The output will
       be:
           <display name>
           <time zone ID>

...

C:\>tzutil /l

...

(UTC-01:00) Azores
Azores Standard Time

(UTC-01:00) Cape Verde Is.
Cape Verde Standard Time

(UTC) Casablanca
Morocco Standard Time

(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time
UTC

(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
GMT Standard Time

(UTC) Monrovia, Reykjavik
Greenwich Standard Time

(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna
W. Europe Standard Time

(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague
Central Europe Standard Time

...
```

Comment: Thx, the time zone is now skipped. However the keyboard locale still pops up. I suppose I have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have the sections [Locale] and [Time Zone] listed in the priority line, or are calling them in some other way (such as a variable), you are skipping these sections. Do not separate the sections with the section headings in square brackets. Remove

```
[Locale]
```

And

```
[Time Zone]
```

Just keep these settings all under the [Default] section.

Since you are using MDT, you can also set these settings in the Task Sequences.

Remember, any changes to the bootstrap.ini require that you regenerate your boot images.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following on 2 MDT building different domains:

```
SkipLocaleSelection=YES
KeyBoardLocale=en-GB
UserLocal=en-GB
UILanguage=en-GB

SkipTimeZone=Yes
TimeZoneName=UTC
```

on our other system all the same except for:

```
TimeZoneName=GMT Standard Time
```